# How to replace or remove parts from columns in pandas DataFrame which are irregular?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

One in my columns in my pandas DataFrame has very irregular expressions. I want to remove everything except the coordinates. However, I cannot just use the replace or remove function since the parts of what I want to remove are different in each column. Is there a way of picking just the part of the strings which I actually want to use?

One cell looks like this:

```
 {'is_geometry': True, 'configuration': 'technologies', 'additional_translations': {}, 'key': 'Map', 'value': '{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":1549869006355,"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[67.91225703380735,34.69585762863356]},"properties":null}]}', 'map_url': '/en/technologies/view/technologies_1723/map/', 'template': 'raw'}
```

where the id and the map_url are always different. I would like to only have [67.91225703380735,34.69585762863356] in this example. Further, is there a way of turning the two values around in order that I have [34.69585762863356,67.91225703380735] instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but assuming your dataframe's column contains dicts that are like your example, this should work:

```
import ast
import json
df['nums'] = df.loc[df['tech_map'].notna(), 'tech_map'].astype(str).apply(ast.literal_eval).str['value'].apply(json.loads).str['features'].str[0].str['geometry'].str['coordinates'].str[::-1]
```

Two notes:
- The above is basically equivalent to doing `json.loads(row['value'])['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][::-1]` for each row
- `[::-1]` reverse a list

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! It gives me an error though: "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not float" Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: There must be a float in `value` somewhere. So are not all the items in `value` JSON objects?

Comment: It is a pandas dataframe and the column is tech_map which has something like what I posted in a cell or NaN. Do I need to convert a cell into json or something?

Comment: I had read every value in a column cell as dtype string so the whole cell content is one big string I guess

Comment: Ah! That's the problem. NaN is a float, thus the error. That's easy enough to fix, but one more question: are the JSON objects in `tech_map` strings that _look like_ JSON or real JSON? Run `print(type(df['tech_map'].iloc[XXX]))` - where XXX is the index of a non-nan row - and send the result.

Comment: Okay, check now. It should work for you :)

Comment: I guess they only look like json since I specified string for every column as datatype. Here is what I get when running your command: <class 'str'>

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. I updated the answer to account for that.

Comment: Amazing! You're a genius. Many thanks! :))

Comment: You're welcome! :D More ways of thanks can be found on [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17242583/richardec?tab=profile) :)